# Adding Models to the silverlight wcf ria services enabled application

Tags: silverlight, mvvm-light

I have started using the MVVm light2 framework for the wcf ria enabled silverlight 4.0 application.

I was able to add a folder named "Models" to ASP .Net application that hosts the silverlight application, I added a class to this folder, and i am able to set the properties and all for this in my silverlight application, but once i started to add more such classes into my Models folders, they aren't getting accessible anywhere in my silverlight application.

Also in my MainViewModel.cs the intellisense is not showing the newly added class/classes , i made sure the application is build before i accessed them in my silvelight application, also the namespaces are correct.

Am I missing to set a property or something?

Comment: Make sure the objects are exposed/used in the RIA domain service. Otherwise they wont be generated to the silverlight project.

Answer (score 0):

Someone on my team faced a similar problem. As I recall it had something to do with the physical location on the .cs files, which may imply that the namespace had changed.